# MySQL: INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not triggering a AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a confusing Problem.
I am using 5.6.12 Community Version.

I have an AFTER UPDATE Trigger, that is working correctly, when the table is called with for example

```
UPDATE test_table SET TestVariable = 2 WHERE TestIndex = 2;
```

But when I use

```
INSERT INTO test_table (TestIndex,TestVariable) VALUES (2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TestVariable = 3;
```

the UPDATE-Trigger is not "triggered".

This is of course a heavily simplified case and has nothing to do with my current code. I have not found much information about this. In my opinion the UPDATE on a DUPLICTE KEY is internaly a normal UPDATE and should call my trigger.

Has anyone made similar observations, or can explain to me, why MySQL is behaving that way, or assure me, that I must have some error in my setup, because it should work?

I do NOT need a answer suggesting, that I should NOT use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICTE KEY ..., because 
a) thats not the question
and
b) I can not easily modify the business application i currently work on.

Thank you so much for your Help

Comment: it would suggest (Mihai) that the update part failed on IODKU. So instead of blaming the update trigger, focus on the IODKU failure or potential failure. Meaning your update never happened, but rather unwanted inserts

Comment: So you are focusing on the wrong thing first, as you have not shown that IODKU even works (based on a unique key clash)

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten that part. The UPDATE takes place. That ist not the Problem. But you would agree, that it should trigger?

Comment: yes I would agree Turm

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57511/79869

Comment: In an after update trigger you cant update new or old values.

Comment: which then begs the question. What was trigger trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this on the smalles possible scale and came to a conclusion.

1. The Update trigger works, like you would expect it. It gets called by the `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`. I could reproduce this by calling the queries from console.
2. The Update trigger is not called (as I reported) when I execute the query from my .net code, using the Oracle .net connector! I have installed the current version 6.9.8.0. To this moment I do not know, if this is a bug in the current version, or if this is a generall issue. I will investigate this further, but for this case, my question is answered.

The issue is for clerification not a MySQL problem, but a connector problem.

Thank you for your help, People.